# Need help to change TextView

Tags: android, textview, multilingual

I'm trying to change a text dynamically for a TicTacToe game.

```
leTexte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

I want to put on screen a TextView wich is going to change, for example if the player X won the game, "Player X won" will be displayed, or "Joueur X gagne" in French.

It's easy for me to do this manually in only one language by using

```
leTexte.setText("Player X Won");
```

But I want to use my XML files for many other languages. Here a sample of the main XML

```
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:text="@string/text"
```

And the english Strings.xml looks like this

```
    <string name="text"></string> //nothing at start
    <string name="textX">Player X Wins</string>
    <string name="textO">Player O Won !</string>
    <string name="textT">TIE !</string>
    <string name="textU">Your Turn</string>
```

So, how can I change the text by using the "name" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to strings in strings.xml as below

```
 tv.setText(R.string.text);
```

In code: Using an static integer from a sub-class of your R class, such as:

R.string.text

string is the resource type and text is the resource name.

More details at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html.

Comment: It is not possible in this world to get the string name without `getResources().getString(id)`

Comment: you are suggesting you cannot set text this way?

Comment: I haven't find any method like setText which access integer  check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29

Comment: msgTextView.setText(R.string.hello_message); in the same link you provided just above the caution

Comment: the answer of @Raghunandan is correct, use `TextView.setText(int resId);` directly from your code, all what you need is to specify each Strings for each language in `res/values` , `res/values-fr` , `res/values-de`, and they should be declared with the same `android:name` value